# weblogic ssl with custom truststore

Tags: sockets, ssl, weblogic

Is it possible that weblogic uses a custom ssl socket implementation? I'm running into a problem with the JavaMail. Trying to use a smtp ssl connection fails even though I've setup a custom truststore with the mailserver ca. However if I set the javax.net.ssl.trustStore property to use a truststore with the mailserver ca everything works.

This makes me think that weblogic uses their custom sockets or custom config for sockets. While JavaMail relies on the standard mechanisms and will not take into account what's in the weblogic custom truststore.

Any ideas?

Comment: WebLogic Server doesn't use custom socket implementation that I'm aware of. I've integrated it in the past with a number of client applications or other servers. That being said, SSL is gloriously frustrating to get working right. Can you post the exceptions/errors you're getting in your logs when WebLogic Server tries to make the connection? If you're not seeing anything in the logs, depending on the version of WebLogic Server you're using, there are a number of debug flags you can enable to get more information.

Comment: Hi Kevin, the exceptions that I get are that the mailserver CA cannot be found in the truststore. This occurs when the mailserver CA is in the weblogic truststore. When I use the global vm property (javax.net.ssl.trustStore), everything works fine... It very much looks as if JavaMail doesn't use the weblogic truststore mechanisms, but solely relies on the jvm property. From my undestanding of appservers, the resources like the truststore should be managed by the server though. Am I right with my assumption, that JavaMail doesn't use the wls truststore mechanism?

Comment: Write your answer as an answer, so that I can +1 your answer!

Answer (score 1):

(posted as an answer - thanks!)

WebLogic Server doesn't use custom socket implementation that I'm aware of. I've integrated it in the past with a number of client applications or other servers. That being said, SSL is gloriously frustrating to get working right. Can you post the exceptions/errors you're getting in your logs when WebLogic Server tries to make the connection? If you're not seeing anything in the logs, depending on the version of WebLogic Server you're using, there are a number of debug flags you can enable to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

By default WebLogic uses the Certicom SSL implementation. My experience of this library has been nothing but grief. You haven't provided any details of the error but I would enable the Sun implementation to see if that helps. In the "Advanced" tab in the SSL-configuration there is a checkbox called  "Use JSSE SSL" which will do it.

Or you can do it with system properties like so:

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/09/enforce-weblogic-to-use-sun-ssl-implementation-rather-than-certicom/

Comment: I concur, Weblogic is using Certicom SSL by default on WLS up to 10g and it completely ignores the custom trustStore and the custom TrustManager. Forcing JSSE SSL did solve the problem for me but I'm afraid it might have unexpected side-effects.

Comment: The content in the article linked above doesn't apply to 12c and above anymore (https://blogs.oracle.com/vijaya/entry/enable_disable_ssl_jsse_in)